# Update Database if Application Close unexpectedly in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing desktop based winform  in c#.
  The application may closed unexpectedly (power failure or debug mode off).
  In any closing condition i need to update my database .
  i.e. I need to change the online status from 1 to 0
 how to do this?

Comment: Did you really think that question through?  If the power fails then your computer is off so how is your application going to magically save data to a database?

Comment: You will need the database externally and another program to "ask" if the desktop winform is alive.

Comment: Obviously the crashing application will not be able to perform a database update. An option that can be tried is to have a mechanism in the application to periodically (say every 5 minutes) updates the current time in a database table. Anyone who checks the online status, should also check the last time at which the application updated this time field. If the last updated time value is greater than a value (say 6 - 10 minutes), then we can assume that the application is offline/crashed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know whether an application has died is not to try to think of a way to update the database when the application closes; but rather, you could create a "session" record whenever the application is opened; then "ping" the record (i.e. there's a LastPingUTC column) every minute.

If the application closes for whatever reason, the LastPingUTC value will be over 1 minute ago and therefore you can assume the application / session is dead.

Actually, I'd assume a given session is dead after 5 minutes as updating a column may be delayed.